# how to fix http request to kafka server via AWS lambda connection time out?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

First of all I want to mention that I am new to AWS and Kafka.

My Kafka server which is deployed on AWS EC2 instance triggers lambda whenever producer produces in a topic. The lambda function tries to call the consumer api to consume from that topic but the http connection which lambda tries to create fails due to timeout. The lambda function is in the same vpc as the kafka server.

I have tried the following things :

1. checked whether the issue is with only that particular api or with every api. I found that other api e.g. http://google.co.in gives me response without any error.
2. obviously used public ip of kafka server
3. removed from vpc and tried with no vpc, still same issue
4. Attached policy for full access to vpc.

```
            URL url = new URL("http://ec2-*-*-*-*.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/consumers/db_json_consumer/instances/lambda_consumer/topics/kbtest");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            logger.log("Connection : " + conn);

            conn.connect();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                logger.log("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            logger.log("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            logger.log("Response Code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            conn.disconnect();
}
```

```
Execution result: failed(logs)
Details
The area below shows the result returned by your function execution. Learn more about returning results from your function.
{
  "errorMessage": "2019-06-24T12:25:08.529Z 406d0e22-3283-4f02-9c31-cb2163c1b950 Task timed out after 15.02 seconds"
}
Summary
Code SHA-256
Mn3/26Ky/hBE1ONL+LDdYaLEiCQZo6VHdlfcRpF8WYw=
Request ID
406d0e22-3283-4f02-9c31-cb2163c1b950
Duration
15015.27 ms
Billed duration
15000 ms
Resources configured
512 MB
Max memory used
55 MB
Log output
The section below shows the logging calls in your code. These correspond to a single row within the CloudWatch log group corresponding to this Lambda function. Click here to view the CloudWatch log group.
START RequestId: 406d0e22-3283-4f02-9c31-cb2163c1b950 Version: $LATEST
Heyy lambda object : HeyConnection : sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:http://13.235.76.198:8082/consumers/db_json_consumer/instances/lambda_consumer/topics/kbtestEND RequestId: 406d0e22-3283-4f02-9c31-cb2163c1b950
REPORT RequestId: 406d0e22-3283-4f02-9c31-cb2163c1b950  Duration: 15015.27 ms   Billed Duration: 15000 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 55 MB  
2019-06-24T12:25:08.529Z 406d0e22-3283-4f02-9c31-cb2163c1b950 Task timed out after 15.02 seconds
```

Comment: What are the security group rules assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: for inbound it is my public ip as X.X.0.0/16 and for outbound it is for all

Comment: Then your Lambda function is being blocked by your security group rule on the EC2 server. You need to add your Lambda function back to the EC2 server, and assign a security group to the function. Then add a rule to the EC2 security group that allows traffic originating from the Lambda function security group.

Comment: yes, it worked Mark. Thanks.